# Using Arcpy to clip Features in Workspace

Tags: arcpy, clip

I'm trying to write a program that clips all the features in a workspace.  I've read through several similar threads on this website, but still am having trouble understanding what is wrong with my program.

```
# This program clips all roads, state roads, railroads, steams, rivers, and
# land use using the Meridian Township boundary.  Each clipped dataset is
# renamed to the base name plus "_Meridian.shp"


import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "F:/data"

clipFeature = 'Meridian.shp'

appendstring = '_Meridian'

featureClassList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
# this gets the base name variable
clipFeatureName = arcpy.Describe(clipFeature)
clipName = str(clipFeatureName.baseName)

try:
    for featureClass in featureClassList:
        featureClassDescription = arcpy.Describe(featureClass)
        featureClassList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        #this gets the base name variable
        nameString = str(featureClassDescription.baseName)
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(featureClassList, clipFeature, "F:/output")

        # this statement prevents the clip feature from clipping itself.
        if nameString == clipName:
            pass
        else:
            namething = nameString + appendstring
            print namething

except:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
```

Update: My program does not produce an error message, but when I look in my output folder in arccatalog, it is empty.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post to include the error message.

Comment: The error message means that `Meridian.shp` isn't in folder `F:/data`.

Comment: I had a typo in the path name.  But now, when I run the program, there is no error message, but my output folder is empty after refreshing arcCatalog.

Comment: You should update your post, or remove the error message, I didn't realize you figure out the error and now have a different issue.

Comment: You could skip the desc to get the name, just put them into a folder that says clipped. Also it looks like your clip_analysis has a folder for the shapefile name(output). Lastly you should check the name before you run clip_analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, it's simple and works.

```
# http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/clip.htm
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
env.workspace = "C:/data/demo"

fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for i in fc:
    if (i != "clip.shp"):
        in_features = i
        clip_features = "clip.shp"
        out_feature_class = "C:/data/output/"+i
        arcpy.Clip_analysis(in_features, clip_features, out_feature_class)

print "Done"
```